# Controls not aligning correctly even after setting width via bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a UI that would contain four controls on each row. It would have a label and control followed by another label and control. If you see in my markup i have set col-md-2 for label and col-md-4 for the control but the second control seems to wrap and go on the next line. I am not sure why it is doing this because in total it is width 12. If you click the Edit button on the top right corner , you could toggle to see the controls

I have also created a stackblitz to replicate the issue

https://angular-lmck2c.stackblitz.io

Markup

```
<style>
    label {
        margin-left: 0.5rem;
        vertical-align: middle
    }


    .panel-heading {
        color: black;
        /* background-color: #F5F7F7; */
        border-color: #ddd;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-top: 5px !important;
        padding-bottom: 5px !important;
    }

    .panel-heading .left-label {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-top: 5px !important;

    }
    .panel-heading label {
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }
</style>



<div class="card" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <div class="card-header panel-heading">
        <span class="left-label" style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; ">Fund Terms</span>
        <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right:10px; display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle">
            <label style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle" class="btn btn-primary"
                [ngClass]="{'btn-primary': EditMode, 'btn-default': !EditMode }"><input type="checkbox"
                    [(ngModel)]="EditMode" class="hidden" />Edit Mode</label>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">


            <div class="form-group row" style="width: 100%;">

                <label for="inputName" class="col-md-2  col-form-label modal-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">Test Name</div>
                    <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                        />
                </div>

                <label for="inputOffice" class="col-md-2 col-form-label ">Side Letter Agreement</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">Test</div>
                    <label *ngIf="EditMode" style="font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;cursor: pointer">
                        <input type="checkbox" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />
                        Yes </label>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputTitle" class="col-md-2  col-form-label ">Vehicle Type</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">Test Vehicle Type</div>
                    <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                        [filterable]="false" textField="NAME" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="ID">
                    </kendo-dropdownlist>
                </div>


                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2  col-form-label ">Side Letter Details</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">Test</div>
                    <textarea *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextArea></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">

                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group row">

                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2  col-form-label ">Investment Manager (Firm)</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">Test</div>
                    <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                </div>

                <label for="inputTitle" class="col-md-2  col-form-label ">Plan Asset Fund</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">Test Asset Fund</div>
                    <label style="font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;cursor: pointer">
                        <input type="checkbox" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />
                        Yes </label>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">

                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2  col-form-label ">Investment Manager (Firm)</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">Test</div>
                    <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                </div>



            </div>


            <div class="form-group row">

                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2  col-form-label ">NAV Reporting Cycle</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">Test</div>
                    <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                        [filterable]="false" textField="NAME" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="ID">
                    </kendo-dropdownlist>
                </div>



            </div>


            <div class="form-group row">

                <label for="inputName" class="col-md-2  col-form-label ">Fund Currency</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div>Test</div>
                </div>



            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">

                <label for="inputName" class="col-md-2  col-form-label ">Audit Year End</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div>Test</div>
                </div>



            </div>





        <div class="btn-toolbar" style="padding-top:40px;">

            <span *ngIf="EditMode"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all btn mr-3"
                    (click)="saveManager()">Save</button>

            </span>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The stackblitz link not working.

Comment: The stackblitz link not working

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is because your labels have a margin-left. If you take that out, the elements should all fit on one row.

Generally, when items don't fit in the Bootstrap rows, my first check is always to see if there's extra margins or padding somewhere there shouldn't be.

If you do need that extra spacing before the labels, try wrapping them in a containing div, and adding the .col-* class on that wrap instead. Then you can try adding the extra spacing to the label.

`<div class="col-md-4">
    <label></label>
</div>`

Comment: If I am removing marginleft and putting the control in the label then the control is wrapping down the label. I need the label and control to be on the same line

Comment: <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="inputName" class="col-md-2  col-form-label modal-label">Name</label>
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">Test Name</div>
                    <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                        />
                </div>

Comment: I don't have stackblitz -- your link wasn't working -- but I have this CodePen that I hope will help. Check the comment in the first line of the CSS. This allows the items to fit on one row. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LowGaa

Answer (score 0):

I tidied up your code a bit, have a look and see if this works for you.

```css
.panel-heading {
  color: black;
  /* background-color: #F5F7F7; */
  border-color: #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.panel-heading .left-label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.panel-heading label {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card w-100">
  <div class="card-header panel-heading">
    <span class="left-label">Fund Terms</span>
    <div class="float-right">
      <label style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle" class="btn btn-primary" [ngclass]="{'btn-primary': EditMode, 'btn-default': !EditMode }"><input type="checkbox" [(ngmodel)]="EditMode" class="hidden">Edit Mode</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-body">

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputName" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div *ngif="!EditMode">Test Name</div>
        <input *ngif="EditMode" kendotextbox="" [readonly]="false" class="form-control form-control-sm">
      </div>

      <label for="inputOffice" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Side Letter Agreement</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div *ngif="!EditMode">Test</div>
        <div *ngif="EditMode" class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
          <label class="form-check-label">Yes</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputTitle" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Vehicle Type</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div *ngif="!EditMode">Test Vehicle Type</div>
        <kendo-dropdownlist *ngif="EditMode" class="form-control form-control-sm" [filterable]="false" textfield="NAME" [valueprimitive]="true" valuefield="ID">
        </kendo-dropdownlist>
      </div>

      <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Side Letter Details</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div *ngif="!EditMode">Test</div>
        <textarea *ngif="EditMode" kendotextarea="" class="form-control form-control-sm"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Investment Manager (Firm)</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div *ngif="!EditMode">Test</div>
        <input *ngif="EditMode" kendotextbox="" [readonly]="false" class="form-control form-control-sm">
      </div>

      <label for="inputTitle" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Plan Asset Fund</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div *ngif="!EditMode">Test Asset Fund</div>
        <div *ngif="EditMode" class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
          <label class="form-check-label">Yes</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Investment Manager (Firm)</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div *ngif="!EditMode">Test</div>
        <input *ngif="EditMode" kendotextbox="" [readonly]="false" class="form-control form-control-sm">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">NAV Reporting Cycle</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div *ngif="!EditMode">Test</div>
        <kendo-dropdownlist *ngif="EditMode" class="form-control form-control-sm" [filterable]="false" textfield="NAME" [valueprimitive]="true" valuefield="ID">
        </kendo-dropdownlist>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputName" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Fund Currency</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div>Test</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputName" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Audit Year End</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div>Test</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-toolbar" style="padding-top:40px;">
      <span *ngif="EditMode"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all btn mr-3" (click)="saveManager()">Save</button></span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

If you still want to set a left margin on the labels, you can either wrap the `label` in a containing `div`:

```css
.col-form-label {
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="inputName" class="col-form-label">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        ...
```

or wrap the label text in a `span`:

```css
.col-form-label span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputName" class="col-md-2 col-form-label"><span>Name</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        ...
```